# Adding user in wildfly using add-user.bat/add-user.sh does not write in mgmt-users.properties

Tags: wildfly

Hello I am trying to add new user in my wildfly-19 using `add-user.bat/add-user.sh` and it works fine. But when I checked the location/file(mgmt-user.properties, etc.) where it should be created there's nothing there. Also, when I am trying to add another user with same `username` it can detect that I already have a user with that information but I can't login in management console using that credentials.

**add-user.bat**
[image: add-user.bat]

**mgmt-user.properties**
[image: mgmt-user.properties]

**add-user.bat(existing username)**
[image: add-user.bat(existing username)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that it is being contained by my antivirus and the users that I created is being created in a virtual folder. Our company uses COMODO antivirus, I contacted our security person to whitelist my wildfly. Now it's running as expected.

I'll just leave it here for someone who will run into same issue in the future.